# Rshiny app gives error 'mydata not found', but in my console it runs fine

Tags: shiny

## Rshiny: mydata not found

Hello! My Rshiny app runs well in the console, but once I clear the R enviorment and run RunApp(), it gives the error ‘*mydata not found*’.
However, I have defined *mydata* prior to the ui() and server() functions, and even additionally within the server function, but still it is not recognized.
Can someone please advice?

Below is my server() code. The getTG() functions (from gamlss package) gives the error. It relies on 'mydata', which was used to fit the gamlss object gmod.

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

 output$plot_irt <- renderPlot(
    width=600,
    height =400,
    {

  if(input$Education_dich==0){educ=0}else{educ=1}
  
  mydata=read.csv('data/mydata.csv',header=T, sep = '\t')
  
  gmod=gamlss(IADL_IRT_transf ~ cs(Age, by = as.factor(Education_dich)) + 
                as.factor(Education_dich), family = BE, data = mydata, trace = FALSE)
  
  newdata=setNames(data.frame(matrix(ncol = 6, nrow = 1)), c('RecordID','Age','Education_dich','Sex','IADL_IRT','IADL_IRT_transf'))
  newdata$Age <- input$Age
  newdata$Education_dich <- educ
  newdata$IADL_IRT <- input$IADL_IRT
  newdata$IADL_IRT_transf <- input$IADL_IRT/100
  
  NORM <- getTGD(gmod, newdata=newdata)$resid 

  perc=ecdf(df_healthy$IADL_IRT_NORM)(NORM) * 100 
  perc=round(perc,0)
  if(NORM <=-1.85) { cutoff_result<-'dementia'}else{cutoff_result <- 'normal cognition'}
  if(NORM < 0){mytext='below'}else{mytext='above'}
  
  ## density plot
  dplot + geom_vline(xintercept = NORM, color='red') +
    geom_label(x=NORM, y=1,label=paste0(perc, 'th\npercentile'), show.legend = F, fill='white') 
  })
```

For replication purposes, you can also use the iris dataset in R and run the below code. It will also get an error for the getTGD() function (although a different one - but it may help).

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(gamlss)

data("iris")
iris=subset(iris, Species !='setosa')
iris$Species =ifelse(iris$Species=='versicolor',1,0)
plot <- ggplot(data = iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length)) + geom_histogram()


ui <- fluidPage(
    
    titlePanel('Mytitle'),
    
    navbarPage("Choose a tab:",
               tabPanel("Tab1",
                        sidebarLayout(
                            sidebarPanel(numericInput("Petal.Length", "Petal Length", min = 1, max = 7, value = 4, step=0.01),
                                         numericInput("Petal.Width", "Petal Width", min = 0.1, max = 2.5, value = 1.3, step=0.01),
                                         selectInput("Species", "Species",choices=c('species1'=1,'species2' =2) )),
                            mainPanel( plotOutput("myplot", width = 150, height = 100))
                            )),

               tabPanel("Tab2",
                            mainPanel(  fluidRow( column(width=12,
                                       hr() ))))
    )
) 


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
    output$myplot <- renderPlot(
        width=600,
        height =400,
        {
        
            if(input$Species==0){spec=0}else{spec=1}

            gmod=gamlss(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Species, family = NO, data = iris, trace = FALSE)
            
            NORM <- tryCatch(
              getTGD(gmod, newdata=iris[1,])$resid,
              error = function(err) {
                cat('Error with getTGD().', err$message, "\n") })

            plot + ggtitle(paste0(NORM))

       } )}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1):

Pay attention on the path where You keep Your data - 'data/mydata.csv'. When a shiny app starts it treats the directory where the app.R (or server.R/ui.R) is stored as its root directory. So Your app assumes the following file structure (or similar):

```
(app root)
  |
  + app.R
  L data
     L mydata.csv
```

Make sure it's corrects. Moreover, wrap data reading in `tryCatch` block like this:

```
mydata <- tryCatch({
  read.csv('data/mydata.csv',header=T, sep = '\t')
}, error = function(err) {
  cat('Error while reading mydata.csv.', err$message, "\n)
}
```

Run the app and see if the error occurred here. Alternatively, provide the absolute path to the data file, e.g. /home/data/mydata.csv or C:\Users\justme\data\mydata.csv.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply! The error is not related to reading the data, this is OK. However, mydata is not recognized when running the getTGD() function, which needs mydata in the R enviorment.

Comment: In this case I'd suggest to plase browser() call inside renderPlot and go step by step through the code to examine all the objects created along. I'm not an expert in gamlss package, but it would be very strange if there was indirect dependency inside getTGD function to a variable residing in another environment. I would rather expect there's something wrong with the model - the gmod object. Please verify the model variable is fitted properly as this is the only potential place connected to mydata object.

Comment: Thanks again! The getTGD function works fine within my console though, and the gmod object is OK. The problem specifically occurs once I clean the R environment and RunApp().

Comment: Can You please attach a sample from Your data for reproducibility? Is it complete server code? There's missing '}' at the end. Having sample data I could give You hints how to refactor the app and debug

Comment: I have updated my question with a general code based on the Iris dataset. Perhaps this works for reproducibility?

Comment: could you still help?

Comment: I tried to run the app with the iris dataset and it's not working. But this is a separate problem, not related to Your original question. If You need to solve the original issue, please prepare a dataset consistent with mydata.csv file. Now we have two different issues to solve

Comment: Thank you Jakub. Can I send you the anonymized data by email? I prefer not to upload it here (if that is even possible).

Comment: I must say no. If You cannot prepare a sample anonymized data and attach it to the question I'm affraid no one would be able to help You

Comment: thanks I understand. I have prepared a dataset but don't know how to upload it. Please also see the following link for an updated question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76475168/21924143 
When I bring my code back to the minimal example, I get another error (see link). The current question is therefore not relevant anymore.